# Error 404 en script de sincronización, antes funcionaba bien

Tags: php, wordpress

Buenos días.

Tengo un script en wordpress que empieza con este código

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

pero desde hace una semana ha dejado de funcionar, da un error 404 y no sé porqué
la url es https://www.xnowmate.com/cron/ord.php

sabeis a qué se puede deber? es cuando hace el require cuando salta el error 404...

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Revisa que cambios hiciste en ese tiempo. Verifica que los archivo involucrados existan. Activa el debug de tu sitio y actualiza tu pregunta con la información relevente. Tal como está planteada actualmente, no siempre podría reproducirse.

Comment: En cuanto a la 1ª línea: Esta constante: `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` es posible que ya esté definida en otra parte del WP, para verificar si es así, puedes empezar tu script con esto por ejemplo: `print_r(WP_USE_THEMES);`   En cuanto a la 2ª línea: `require('../wp-blog-header.php');`, ese es uno de los primeros `require` que hace un sitio WP al cargar, por lo cual sobra en tu código. En resumen, la 2ª línea sobra, y la 1ª, estoy casi seguro que también. Si puedes, mira el `error_log` y verás los códigos de error más precisos, con detalle.